# Remove ^M characters from file using ansible

Tags: ansible

I want remove ^M appended at the end of each line using ansible replace module. Is it possible using replace module instead of sed command ?

file.pem

```
---------BEGIN CRTIFICATE----------^M
kjsadhkaj23lk4alskxalskm23lkmsldkmc^M
asljnas8asndj3qwlkmsclkasmlwldkcmsa^M
sdkns98uiasnxalksm3sldkcslcmsldmlms^M
sdfsdfsd.,44sdsdf^M
--------END CERTFICATE-------------
```

Comment: Unless Ansible is putting that character combination in the file directly, it'd probably be way faster to just remove them yourself I think.

Comment: Just for the record if someone is interested in why the character is there and where it came from: [What is `^M` and how do I get rid of it?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/), [Remove `^M` character from log files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88811/) and [What is the `^M` character called?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134695/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the file

```bash
shell> cat cert.txt 
---------BEGIN CRTIFICATE----------^M
kjsadhkaj23lk4alskxalskm23lkmsldkmc^M
asljnas8asndj3qwlkmsclkasmlwldkcmsa^M
sdkns98uiasnxalksm3sldkcslcmsldmlms^M
sdfsdfsd.,44sdsdf^M
--------END CERTFICATE-------------
```

Escape the caret `^`. For example,

```yaml
    - replace:
        path: cert.txt
        regexp: '\^M'
        replace: ''
```

running in `--check --diff` works as expected

```bash
TASK [replace] ********************************************************************************
--- before: cert.txt
+++ after: cert.txt
@@ -1,6 +1,6 @@
----------BEGIN CRTIFICATE----------^M
-kjsadhkaj23lk4alskxalskm23lkmsldkmc^M
-asljnas8asndj3qwlkmsclkasmlwldkcmsa^M
-sdkns98uiasnxalksm3sldkcslcmsldmlms^M
-sdfsdfsd.,44sdsdf^M
+---------BEGIN CRTIFICATE----------
+kjsadhkaj23lk4alskxalskm23lkmsldkmc
+asljnas8asndj3qwlkmsclkasmlwldkcmsa
+sdkns98uiasnxalksm3sldkcslcmsldmlms
+sdfsdfsd.,44sdsdf
 --------END CERTFICATE-------------
```

Comment: I tried `regexp: '\r'` and it worked for me

Comment: Right. For details see the comment by U880D.